# Regex containing negative lookahead is matching entire string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this text:

```
Name: <% $person %> <& component &>
```

and i'm trying to come up with a Ruby regex that will give me everything that **doesn't** look like `<% .. %>` or by `<& ... &>`.

This is my approach using negative lookahead:

```
(?!<&|<%)(.+\s*)(?!&>|%>)
```

but it returns the whole string (tested [here](http://rubular.com/)), when I expected it to return `Name:`.

Comment: It is impossible to match a text other than a sequence of 2+ chars with Ruby regex. With PCRE, it is possible using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`, and in Lucene with the complement operator, but these are not supported by Onigmo.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is an option for you to replace everything in your string that is between `<% .. %>` or `<& ... &>` with an empty string:

[`(?:<%[^%]+%>|<&[^&]+&>)`](http://rubular.com/r/u65nyKOX6L)

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/NavajowhiteGainsboroPooch)

Comment: That's what I was about to say. I believe regex are meant to **match** text. They are not performing well for the opposite operation even when it can be used that way, as far as I know.

Comment: No, sorry, I cannot replace strings. The tool I'm using doesn't allow it (I'm building a syntax highlighter using Rouge)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

- `(?<=^|[&%]>)` - Positive lookbehind: Either start of text or
  a "closing" marker (`&>` or `%>`).
- `(.+?)` - This is what you want to capture. Note the `?` after `+`,
  the **reluctant** version, preventing from "consuming" the whole rest
  of text.
- `(?=<[&%]|$)` - Positive lookahead: Either an "opening"
  marker (`<&` or `<%`) or end of text.

To sum up:

```
(?<=^|[&%]>)(.+?)(?=<[&%]|$)
```

Comment: Interesting, careful though, it matches a text surrounded by the markers if it's placed directly at the start of the string.